# Unexpected Javascript DOM event listener issues

Tags: javascript, dom, listener, dom-events

I have created a function which checks the two password fields, however when I fix the input only one field gets the success class and the other one doesn't; in order for both fields to have success class you have to click back onto it for it to update. What DOM event can I use to update this straight away?

```
window.onload = addListeners;

function addListeners() {

    if(window.addEventListener) {
        _('pass1').addEventListener("blur", checkPassword, false);
        _('pass2').addEventListener("blur", checkPassword, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        _('pass1').attachEvent("onblur", checkPassword);
        _('pass2').attachEvent("onblur", checkPassword);
    }

}

// Index pages field checker
function checkPassword() {

    var p1Val = _("pass1").value;
    var p2Val = _("pass2").value;

    var p1 = _("pass1");
    var p2 = _("pass2");

    if(p1Val != p2Val) {
        this.className = this.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suSuccess(?!\S)/g , '' );
        this.className += " suError";
        _("pass2Check").innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if (p1Val == "" && p2Val == ""){
        p1.className = p1.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suSuccess(?!\S)/g , '' );
        p2.className = p2.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suSuccess(?!\S)/g , '' );
        p1.className += " suError";
        p2.className += " suError";
        _("pass2Check").innerHTML = "Fill in both password fields";
    } else {
        this.className = this.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suError(?!\S)/g , '' );
        this.className += " suSuccess";
        _("pass2Check").innerHTML = "Your password fields match";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `_('pass2')` do..? Can you provide the minimal `HTML` and CSS` required o reproduce this, or a simple online demo..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, when the validation succeeds as well as when the values doesn't match, You are only performing the operations on `this`, which is the element that triggered the event, and the other input is left as it is until you trigger it's on handler.

Change your function as follows:

```
function checkPassword() {

  var p1 = _("pass1");
  var p2 = _("pass2");
  // Here you can avoid an additional DOM traversal by storing the reference first
  var p1Val = p1.value;
  var p2Val = p2.value;

  // You can combine the invalid conditions using || operator
  if(p1Val != p2Val || p1Val == "" && p2Val == ""){ 
    p1.className = p1.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suSuccess(?!\S)/g , '' );
    p2.className = p2.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suSuccess(?!\S)/g , '' );
    p1.className += " suError";
    p2.className += " suError";
    _("pass2Check").innerHTML = "Fill in both password fields";
  } else {
    p1.className = p1.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suError(?!\S)/g , '' );
    p2.className = p2.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)suError(?!\S)/g , '' );
    p1.className += " suSuccess";
    p2.className += " suSuccess";
    _("pass2Check").innerHTML = "Your password fields match";
  }
}
```

---

Side note: You can use the `add()` and `remove()` methods of [classList DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) for adding and removing css classes rather than the regex if older browser support is not an issue.